# How to model nested data with repeated measures

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, nested-data, nested-models

My data is like this: I have `N` students from different courses (variable `course_id`) that where asked about household income (variable `income`) and had to take part in two math tests; one test was considered "income fair" and the other was not (variable `test_type`). The results of the math test are in the variable `test_results`. Each student took both of the tests. And students are grouped in courses. Students have an ID variable `student_id`.

My general question is whether the effect of the income on test results varies depending on the test type, i.e. is smaller for the income fair test. My challenge is now to model this because students are nested in courses (each course has multiple students; each student in just one course) and there is repeated measures (each student takes two tests: the fair and the normal test). I want to take into account that there can be a random intercept and slope of income on test results for  for the courses. How to do this?

I've read and tried so many thing like [this](https://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer) and am quite confused now.. What I do in R is this:

```r
my_fit <- lme4::lmer(test_results ~ income + (1|test_type) + (1|course_id) +
                      (income|course_id), data= anna_long)
summary(my_fit)
```

But I am not sure whether this is correct. And there is no p value for the income predictor... I am lost..

---

Before I also wanted to take into account that there can also be a random intercept and slope for each student and what I did was...

```r
my_fit <- lme4::lmer(test_results~ income + (1|test_type) + 
    (1|course_id/student_id) + (income|course_id/student_id), 
    data= anna_long)
summary(my_fit)
```

... but this resulted in the error

> number of observations (=361) <= number of random effects (=362)

... Therefore I discarded the random effects associated with single students and focused on random effects of courses as shown above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things here:

- it probably doesn't make sense to treat `test_type` as a random effect. Test type may be a **nuisance variable** (i.e., you're not primarily interested in the population-level effect of test type), but (1) the levels (income-fair or not) aren't really exchangeable and (2) it's impractical to estimate a variance from only two observations (which is effectively what you would be trying to do).
- "students are nested in courses (each course has multiple students; each student in just one course)": this means you would normally want a random-effect grouping variable of the form `course/student` ... but ...
- presumably `income` varies only across students within courses, not across tests within students, so you can't estimate variation in income effects among students
- you might be interested in variation among students within courses in the difference between test types (`(1+test_type|course:student)`), *but* because you only have two observations per student, this effect is confounded with the residual variance term, leading to the error you saw. (There are ways around this if you really want ...)

So I think you want:

```r
test_results ~ income*test_type + (income*test_type|course) + (1|course:student)
```

where `course:student` is effectively "student within course". The first term adds variation among courses in the slopes *and* intercepts (i.e., expected difference in test results for the two test types at a reference value of income; you might want to center your `income` variable); the second adds a random intercept term for students within courses.

- `lme4` doesn't give p-values for [Reasons](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#why-doesnt-lme4-display-denominator-degrees-of-freedomp-values-what-other-options-do-i-have), but if you load the `lmerTest` package instead of/in addition to `lme4`, *before* fitting your model, the `summary()` output should give you p-values.

Comment: Firstly: Thanks! Do I understand it right that `income*test_type|course` adds random slopes for test types on test results for the courses, and that `1|course:student` adds a random intercept for students within courses?

Comment: See edits .....